# DISTANCE_TYPE_EARSHOT for iOS using Nearby API?

Tags: ios, google-nearby

I see documentation for strategy that has a setDistanceType of DISTANCE_TYPE_EARSHOT (which is what I'd like). Now, for iOS this doesn't seem to be available.

If we set the discoveryMediums to use Audio, does this do the same thing? Wondering why there is no equivalent for iOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, audio on iOS is the same as earshot on Android.  Sorry for the confusion.  We may add the earshot concept on iOS for consistency across platforms.

Comment: What's normally the distance when using earshot? Like is it one meter, two meters or what? And what's the difference between using Earshot and Default